# Oracle: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

`SELECT e.name
        from emp e, departm d, salery s
        WHERE e.dep=d.depid 
                  AND s.emp= e.empid
                  AND s.sal > (SELECT round(avg(s.sal)) as AVGSAL
                               from emp e, departm d, salery s
                               WHERE e.dep=d.depid AND s.emp= e.empid
                               GROUP BY d.depid
                              );`

MY Tables are:

`emp (empid, name, dep)
departm (depid, name, headdep)
salery (emp, cost, sal, fdate)`

I have some foreign keys:
departm: `FOREIGN KEY (headdep) REFERENCES departm(depid)`
emp: `FOREIGN KEY(dep) REFERENCES departm(depid)`
salery: `FOREIGN KEY(emp) REFERENCES emp(empid)`

I want to print a list of all employees which earn more money than the average of theyr department but when i run this query i have an error: `single-row subquery returns more than one row`

Can anyone help me? What's the problem with my query?
Finally I want to create a procedure, but first of all i have to write the query.

Thank you guys...

Comment: what is m.abt column .. there is no table alias m..correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytic functions are the way to go on this query, but your version has several problems.  You would see these problems much more readily if you used proper join syntax.  You seem to be learning SQL, so just remember one simple rule:  NEVER use commas in `from` clauses.

Apart from the syntax problem, you have a problem with your correlated subquery.  Here is a version that should work:

```
SELECT e.vollername
from emp e join
     salery s
     on s.emp= e.empid
WHERE s.sal > (select round(avg(s2.sal)) as AVGSAL
               from emp e2 join
                    salery s2
                    on s2.emp= e2.empid 
               where e2.dep = e.depid
              );
```

Note the removal of the `departm` table from both the inner and the outer queries.  In the outer one, it was merely superfluous.  In the inner one, it prevented the query from producing the correct results because it removed the correlation.

Comment: Thank you, i have to Test it now with The Procedere but it works trank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat easier with analytic functions (I also removed the join with `departm`, since it is not needed):

```
SELECT e.vollername
FROM (
  SELECT 
    e.vollername, 
    s.sal,
    round(avg(s.sal) over (partition by e.dep)) as avg_dep_sal
  FROM 
    emp e
  JOIN salery s ON e.empid = s.emp
)
where sal > avg_dep_sal
```